# jquery if element exist .gt() .slice() or .length() of each list element

Tags: jquery

A list item contains two DIV classes - left and right. Sometimes there is more than one DIV class right. I want to change (e.g. css, hide, remove...) all DIV class right elements except the first. I have tried: .gt () selector.

```
<li class="cf">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right 1</div>
  <div class="right">Right 2</div>
</li>
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <div class="right">Right 1</div>
  <div class="right">Right 2</div>
  <div class="right">Right 3</div>
<li>
</li>
```

He an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/somaberlin/986UA/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('li').find('.right:not(":first")').css( "color", "red" );
```

Working code: http://jsfiddle.net/986UA/3/

Comment: My answer was wrong and it dont deserves upvotes. +1 for yours.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
$('li').each(function(){
   $(this).find('.right:not(:first)').css('color','red');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/986UA/4/)

Answer (score 0):

And in addition. One:

```
$(".right:not(:first)").css( "color", "red" );
```

Two:

```
$(".right").slice(1).css( "color", "red" );
```

Three:

```
$(".right:gt(0)").css( "color", "red" );
```